# Проблема с кодировками. В Encoding.Convert есть баг?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, кодировка

В общем, на работе стоит русская Windows 7, а дома английский Windows 10, так вот на работе с кодировками проблем нету, а дома какие-то кракозябры.

Попробовал вот таким способом подобрать нужную кодировку, но не получилось:

```
        string srcStr = "êàíäèäàò";
        string pattern = "кандидат";
        foreach (var src in Encoding.GetEncodings())
        {
            foreach (var dst in Encoding.GetEncodings())
            {
                var tmp = dst.GetEncoding()
                     .GetString(Encoding.Convert(src.GetEncoding(), dst.GetEncoding(),
                         src.GetEncoding().GetBytes(srcStr)));
                if (tmp== pattern)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{src.CodePage}=>{dst.CodePage}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Хотя вот этот сайт четко определяет нужную кодировку http://www.online-decoder.com/ru

Однако, когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться явно, то опять получаю кракозябры.

Подскажи, в чем мой косяк? Может быть в настройках Win что-нибудь поменять нужно?

В домашней ОС стоит русская локаль для программ без Unicode.

Вообще на работе вот такая строчка работает:

```
currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
```

а вот дома каракули на выходе.

---

Хм...

А вот если так, то кодировка нормально подбирается:

```
  string srcStr = "êàíäèäàò";
            string pattern = "кандидат";
            foreach (var src in Encoding.GetEncodings())
            {
                foreach (var dst in Encoding.GetEncodings())
                {
                    var dstBytes = src.GetEncoding().GetBytes(srcStr);
                    var tmp = dst.GetEncoding().GetString(dstBytes);
                    if (tmp == pattern)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{src.DisplayName}=>{dst.DisplayName}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Разве первый вариант не идентичный последнему варианту?

Comment: Второе, понятно, должно работать. А что означает `dst.GetEncoding()                     .GetString(Encoding.Convert(src.GetEncoding(), dst.GetEncoding(),                         src.GetEncoding().GetBytes(srcStr)))`, я так и не понял.

Comment: Крякозябры появляются, если программа выводит строку, думая, что система в одной кодировке (CP1251), хотя на деле система в другой кодировке (CP1252). Такое бывает, если использовать `Encoding.Default` (что практически всегда является багом).

Comment: @VladD ну первое должно работать по аналогии, как второе. Разве нет? По крайней мере все примеры выглядели так. Единственное, я перебираю кодировки в цикле. Я заметил, что если вместо src.GetEncoding().GetBytes(srcStr) кастовать исходную строку в массив char, а потом каждый элемент приводить к байт, то первый способ работает. Однако,!на том же msdn в примерах используется GetBytes...

Answer (score 4):

Ваши варианты неидентичны.

Логика второго понятна: мы из байтов получили неправильную строку, интерпретируя их в неправильной кодировке. Мы получаем эти байты назад, и интерпретируем в правильной кодировке. При этом, понятно, байты не меняются, потому что это по сути одни и те же байты, мы лишь меняем их интерпретацию.

А ваш первый вариант меняет байты при помощи `Convert`, понятно, что он не равносилен второму. Метод `Convert` работает наоборот: он берёт байты, соответствующие строке в одной кодировке, и превращает их в байты *той же строки* в другой кодировке. То есть

```
var bytes2 = Encoding.Convert(enc1, enc2, bytes);
```

равносильно

```
var s = enc1.GetString(bytes);
var bytes2 = enc2.GetBytes(s);
```

---

Итого: `Convert` даёт байты другой кодировки для той же строки, а второй вариант даёт другую строку для тех же байтов.